# Invalid read of size 1 converting char* to std::string

Tags: c++, valgrind

My test.cpp contains following code. I profiled it with valgrind and valgrind shows errors. What am I missing ?

```
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
#include<iostream>

void TestString(std::string & str)
{
    char * tmpBuff = new char[3];
    tmpBuff[0] = 'f';
    tmpBuff[1] = 'o';
    tmpBuff[2] = 'o';
    str = tmpBuff;
    delete [] tmpBuff;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string test_string;
    TestString(test_string);
    std::cout<<test_string;
    return 0;
}
```

valgrind-log

```
==5026== Invalid read of size 1
==5026==    at 0x4A07F64: strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:403)
==5026==    by 0x347E29E14B: std::string::operator=(char const*) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==5026==    by 0x4009AD: TestString(std::string&) (test.cpp:11)
==5026==    by 0x4009EC: main (test.cpp:18)
==5026==  Address 0x4c22043 is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==5026==    at 0x4A07152: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:363)
==5026==    by 0x400979: TestString(std::string&) (test.cpp:7)
==5026==    by 0x4009EC: main (test.cpp:18)
```

Comment: Can anyone please explain that how even after `str = tmpBuff; delete [] tmpBuff;`, `std::cout<<test_string;` is valid ?

Comment: @MadHatter: `str = tmpBuff` isn't a pointer copy; `std::string` overloads `=` to copy the pointed-to characters.

Comment: @MadHatter `tmpBuff` is a `char*`, the string constructor used is to build its internal data buffer (and fails, because it is not null terminated), then `delete []` de-allocates the memory. Bar the nul termination bug, it is fine, if weird.

Comment: Thanks everyone!! I understood. I am from C background, hence thought `str = tmpBuff;` is copying the pointer value from `tmpBuff` to `str`. Also I failed to notice that `str` is `string` object hence `=` must be an overloaded operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following fix

```
void TestString(std::string & str)
{
    char * tmpBuff = new char[4]; // <<<
    tmpBuff[0] = 'f';
    tmpBuff[1] = 'o';
    tmpBuff[2] = 'o';
    tmpBuff[3] = '\0'; // <<<
    str = tmpBuff;
    delete [] tmpBuff;
}
```

C-style strings need a terminating `\0` character.

Answer (score 3):

`tmpBuff` is missing the terminating `\0`.

It should contain the 4 chars: `'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

The `std::string(const char*)` constructor you are calling expects a [*nul terminated string*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string). You are not passing it one, so the result is *undefined behaviour*. The constructor will try to read until it finds a `\0`.

So, pass a nul terminated string and everything will be fine.